# Maven Selenium Plugin - Lock File still present error

Tags: java, selenium, junit

My Project is using selenium-client-driver 0.9 and selenium based integration test will be executed by maven using maven-selenium-plugin. (There are already many questions in stackoverflow but couldnt find a relavant answer). Selenium test case fails with error 
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher$FileLockRemainedException: Lock file still present! C:\Users\nagappan.s\AppData\Local\Temp\customProfileDir23d2b92949d74270915586b2a3f2073a\parent.lock
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.waitForFileLockToGoAway(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:318)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.waitForFullProfileToBeCreated(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:365)
    ... 20 more

Comment: I am not sure why it is devoted...i have read all the answers of stackoverflow and tried it but didnt worked out. As per the saying, if we use a profile in firefox and try to open another file lock file will not allow it to happen. But after closing all the firefox windows also it happens in the same way. It also has deprecated version which doesnt have any support and i cannot afford to move to newer version of java.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by myself. Maven selenium plugin just start the hub and not the selenium node (both integrated and standalone). In my case, it is old version of selenium 0.9 and unit testing uses DefaultSelenium so it   require a node also which process browser commands by opening browser and console. So i started the hub and node using maven antrun plugin to start the server and hub like

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase> 
        <configuration>
            <target>
                <property name="selenium.server.dir" value="${basedir}" />
                <path id="selenium.classpath">
                    <fileset dir="${selenium.server.dir}">
                        <include name="selenium*.jar" />
                    </fileset>
                </path>     
                <java classname="org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher"
                      classpathref="selenium.classpath"
                      failonerror="true"
                      fork="false">
                    <arg line="-role hub"/>
                </java>
                <java classname="org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher"
                      classpathref="selenium.classpath"
                      failonerror="true"
                      fork="false">
                    <arg line="-role node
                               -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register"/>
                </java>
            </target>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

It works now perfectly.